# Bash - handling of (single) quotes in variables (for a Curl command)

Tags: bash, curl, escaping, quotes

I am writing a script which uses CURL.

There are some HTTP headers common to all requests.

```
curl -X GET "..." -H  'accept: */*' -H "api-key: $API_KEY"
```

So I would like to put those to a variable:

```
HEADERS="-H  'accept: */*' -H \"api-key: $API_KEY\""

curl -X GET "..." $HEADERS      ### <-- This is what I want to achieve.
```

As you can see, it needs a mix of

- `'`s because it contains `*`, which could expand,
- `"`s because there is a variable.

I have tried quite a few combinations of escaping, mixing ' and ", building the string gradually, but always I end up with Bash adding unwanted escapes or leaving those which I need.

**How can I achieve to have both `-H` params (i.e. all 4 arguments) in a variable which I can then use in a command?**

There are a few similar questions but they are specific for other cases.

Comment: What you tried seem to work for me on MacOS with bash 3.2.57. Perhaps you are using an older/bogus version ?

```
$ export API=123; HEADERS="-H  'accept: */*' -H \"api-key: $API\""; echo $HEADERS
-H 'accept: */*' -H "api-key: 123"

```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does shell ignore quotes in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

Comment: You should use an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to **store a list of words** (like, `-H` or `accept: */*`) *where each word may contain whitespace characters*. As `bash` delimits words in a string by whitespace (by default), it's **difficult to use a string variable** for a list of words that possibly contain whitespace characters.

A simple solution is to **use a list variable**. Each list member is a word (and it can thus contain whitepace as needed). When expanding that list, ensure proper quoting. In your case:

```
declare -a HEADERS
HEADERS=(
  '-H' 'accept: */*'
  '-H' 'api-key: $API_KEY'
)
curl -X GET "..." "${HEADERS[@]}"
```

Mind the `"..."` characters when expanding the array. They will ensure that each list item is expanded as a single, dedicated word.